# Raw Javascript for JQuery's fade In for background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to disable background in order to show a small popup window with a video once a user clicks on an image.

I could do it with JQuery but can't seem to understand it in Javascript.

Here what I've done in JQuery:

style snippet:

```
 .overlay {
    z-index: 4;
    position:absolute;
    display:none; 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```

Jquery snippet:

```
$(".overlay").fadeToggle();
```

Html snippet:

```
<div id="bck" class="overlay"></div>
```

In javascript I have tried many things, like:

```
var el = document.getElementById("bck");
function fadeIn(el) {
    el.style.opacity = 0;
    var tick = function() {
        el.style.opacity = +el.style.opacity + 0.01;
        if (+el.style.opacity < 1) {
            (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16)
        }
    };
    tick();
   }
   fadeIn(el);
```

but it's not working

help, please!

Comment: your overlay is always hidden since you have `display: none;` set in your css. try removing that and see. here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6vdo78fo/

Comment: yes, just a few secs ago I realized it, thanks

Comment: you're most welcome @Limon

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Jquery plugin overlay.js. It will make your life much easier.

http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/overlay/

However, if that is not the route you want to go, I did notice a little problem in your code. You have the timeout set to 16 ms. That is too quick to get a proper fade in. Adjusting it to at least 100 ms would have the fade-in take place in one second.

Comment: I wanna do it myself, otherwise I would have used this stuff

Comment: Is the problem you are encountering that your overlay is not properly fading in?